# Jekyll conditional string equality wrong

Tags: jekyll

In the following code, I have a category by the name "ml" defined in my `yml` file frontmatter. For some reason, the `{% unless cat == "ml" %}` is not working properly. See this html, and the output image below. Clearly, the category is `ml` (I have tried to remove any whitespace with the `strip` filter, which did not work), but it is not working (the unless statement, that is).

Please help!

```html
<div class="posts">
  <h1>Recent Posts: </h1>
  {% for post in paginator.posts %}
    {% assign cat = post.categories %}
    {% unless cat == "ml" %}
      <div class="post">
        <h1 class="post-title">
          <a href="{{ post.url }}">
            {{ post.title }}: {{ cat }}
          </a>
          {% if post.image %}
            <img src={{post.image}}>
          {% endif %}

        </h1>

        <span class="post-date">{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span>
      </div>
    {% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[image: jekyll strings]

Comment: Are you 100% sure that what is inside `cat` is the string `ml`? Don't you need to [`strip`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/strip/) it? You can confirm all those doing `{{ cat | json }}` and see what it yields.

Answer (score 0):

I still am not completely sure on the why here, but I found that using `contains` rather than `==` solved my issue.